# The natural projection mapping $\pi : G \to G/N$ defined by $\pi(x) = xN$, for all $x$ in $G$, is a homomorphism, and $\ker(\pi) = N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question again...

> The natural projection mapping $\pi : G \to G/N$ defined by $\pi(x) = xN$, for all $x$ in $G$, is a homomorphism, and $\ker(\pi) = N$.

I am wanting to prove that $\ker(\pi) = N$, where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, but I have been trying to think of a way to begin but I cannot seem to get anywhere despite my multiple efforts.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Given a subgroup $H\leqslant G$ and an element in $a\in G$, we have the **left coset**
$$aH = \{ah :h\in H\}, $$
and similarly the **right coset**
$$Ha = \{ha :h\in h\}. $$
The distinction, of course, is in the order of multiplication. A **normal subgroup** $N\mathrel{\unlhd}G$ is a subgroup of $G$ with the property that
$$gN = Ng \tag 1$$
for all $g\in G$. Another way of stating this is that $N$ is stable under **conjugation**, that is if $n\in N$ and $g\in G$, then $gng^{-1}\in N$ - this is the conjugation of $n$ by $g$. To see this, right-multiplying $(1)$ yields
$$gNg^{-1} = N.$$

Now, to the actual question - the map $\pi:G\to G/N$ with $g\mapsto gN$ is simply the map from $g$ to the left coset of $N$ in $g$. But if $N$ is a normal subgroup, then $gN=Ng$, and hence for $a,b\in G$
$$\pi(a)\pi(b) = (aN)(bN) = (aN)(Nb) = aNb = (aN)b = (ab)N = \pi(ab).$$
Finally, if $a\in\operatorname{Ker}(\pi)$ then $\pi(a)=N$, which is is the same as $aN=N$, which implies that $a\in N$.

Answer (score 1):

Subgroups are closed under the group operation.  If $a\in N$, what is the set $aN=\{an|n\in N\}?$  What is the identity element of $G/N$?  This will give you $N\subseteq\operatorname{ker}(\pi)$.  The reverse implication is quite similar, can you show it?

Comment: I have just seen your comment. I appreciate your help. From the top of my head, isn't $aN$ a partition/left coset of G? And $G/N$ is the set of all left cosets where $G/N$ = ${gN:g\in G}$. Identity should be just $N$, right? My understanding of kernel is that $\ker(\pi)=\{g\in G:\pi(g)=e_{G/N}\}$, but there's only one identity in $G/N$, so am I done? I am bad at this type of math so I apologize.

Comment: Ignore my 2nd to last sentence in my last comment. Sorry... What I don't understand from getting the definition of kernel from Wikipedia is that doesn't $\ker(\pi)$ have to be a set of elements from $G$? Why is $N \subseteq \ker(\pi)$ when $N$ is a coset of $G$, but not an actual element.

Comment: Nevermind I am an idiot... I see that the elements in $N$ are also in $\ker(\pi)$ and I have to show the reverse so show it's equal.

There is a corollary in my text that we can use that says... Let $b$, $c \in G$. If $c \in H*b$, then $H*c=H*b$. So every element $n \in N$ in $n*N = e*N$, right? Am I done?

Comment: Responding to your second comment: $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ so all of its elements are in $G$.  $N$ is also an element of $G/N$, which consists of (left) cosets of $N$ in $G$.

Comment: To your third comment: The argument you've presented there proves that $N\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(\pi)$.  To show the other direction, take an element of $x\in\ker(\pi)$.  Then, by definition, $\pi(x)=xN = N$.  If $xN=N$, what does that tell you about $x$?

Comment: Doesn't that mean $x$ has to be $n$ where $n \in N$, right?

Comment: @user133636 Yes, it means that $x\in N$.  So we've shown that $x\in\operatorname{ker}(\pi)\Rightarrow x\in N$ which means that $\operatorname{ker}(\pi)\subseteq N$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very bad at algebra... I appreciate your quick and helpful responses a lot.

Comment: @user133636 No problem.  Quotient groups are hard, probably the hardest topic in first year algebra, intuition-wise.  Keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a named theorem, called the "first isomorphism theorem". So if you want to see a proof simply open your favorite text on group theory or algebra, turn to the index and look it up. It is such an important theorem that it *will* be there!

It is so important because it says that every normal subgroup corresponds to the kernel of a homomorphism, and of course we know that the kernel of every homomorphism is a normal subgroup. So, normal subgroups and homomorphisms are dual to one another. so, for example, a *simple group* is a group which contains no non-trivial, proper normal subgroups, so we now know that an equivalent definition of a simple group is one which contains no homomorphic images apart from isomorphisms and the trivial map (so, collapsing everything to the identity).

Comment: This isn't the first isomorphism theorem, it doesn't even state an isomorphism.

Comment: @Christoph Well, it is one-half of the theorem. The Theorem states both that $G/\ker(\alpha)\cong \operatorname{im}(\alpha)$, and that the question here holds. (See, for example, *A course in the theory of groups*, D.J.S.Robinson, p19. He splits it exactly like this, although I wouldn't recommend this reference for detailed proof!)